# "Use of uninitialized value" when indexing an array

Tags: arrays, perl, join

I get the following error from Perl when trying to run the code below

```
Use of uninitialized value within @words in concatenation (.) or string...
```

It references the line where I try to create an array made up of three-word sequences (the line that starts with `$trigrams`).  Can anyone help me figure out the problem?

```
my %hash;
my @words;
my $word;
my @trigrams;
my $i = 0;

while (<>) {

   @words = split;

   foreach $word (@words) {
      $hash{$word}++;

      # Now trying to create the distinct six-grams in the 10-K.
      $trigrams[$i] = join " ", $words[$i], $words[$i + 1], $words[$i + 2];

      print "$words[$i]\n";
      $i++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Always `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: Looks like you're moving beyond the end of `@words` with `$words[$i + 1]` and `$words[$i + 2]` when `$i` is the last (or second to last) index.

Answer (score 5):

All that is happening is that you are falling off the end of the array `@words`. You are executing the loop for each element of `@words`, so the value of `$i` goes from 0 to `$#words`, or the index of the final element of the array. So the line

```
join " ", $words[$i], $words[$i + 1], $words[$i + 2];
```

accesses the last element of the array `$words[$i]` and two elements beyond that which don't exist.

In this case, as with any loop which uses the current index of an array, it is easiest to iterate over the array *indices* instead of the contents. For the `join` to be valid you need to start at zero and stop at two elements before the end, so `0 .. $#words-2`.

It is also neater to use an array *slice* to select the three elements for the trigram, and use the fact that interpolating an array into a string, as in `"@array"`, will do the same as `join ' ', @array`. (More precisely, it does `join $", @array`, and `$"` is set to a single space by default.)

I suggest this fix. It is *essential* to `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of every Perl program, and you should declare all your variables using `my` as late as possible.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;

while (<>) {

   my @words = split;
   my @trigrams;

   for my $i (0 .. $#words - 2) {
      my $word = $words[$i];
      ++$hash{$word};

      $trigrams[$i] = "@words[$i,$i+1,$i+2]";

      print "$word\n";
   }
}
```

---

**Update**

You may prefer this if it isn't too terse for you

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;

while (<>) {
   my @words = split;
   my @trigrams = map "@words[$_,$_+1,$_+2]", 0 .. $#words-2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the responses! I will try the suggested fix when I get back to the office!

Comment: I like your map solution more too.  Best we can do considering the amount of divining intent that was required.

Comment: I can confirm that your solution works for me.  Thanks very much!